# Windows 7 can't detect ADB device

Tags: android, windows-7, usb, adb, driver

If I plug in **LG Nexus 5X** to computer with **Win7**. I see only **one** device. It's MTP.

```
USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE6&REV_0310
USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE6
```

But when I plug in the device to computer with Win8 the system detects 2 devices:

```
USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE6&REV_0310&MI_00
USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE6&MI_00
```

and

```
USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE6&REV_0310&MI_01
USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE6&MI_01
```

One for **MTP device** and other for **ADB device**.

So. How can I detect **2 devices** on Win7?

Comment: Do you have the appropriate driver? https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb.html

Mabie you could give us a bit more information...

Comment: Yes. I have driver.
The problem is that Windows 7 doesn't recognase 2 devices. It see just MTP device.
May be it broblem in driver for USB.